# Time Limit Exceeded in C++ Online Judge

Tags: c++

I just sent the solution to a problem COJ written in C ++. The problem is this link: http://coj.uci.cu/24h/problem.xhtml?pid=1839
This is my solution:

```
  #include<iostream>

  using namespace std;

  unsigned int t, n;

  int main(){

     cin >> t;

    while(t > 0 && cin >> n){
        cout<< ( n * 8 ) + 42 << endl;
        t--;
    }
    return 0;
  }
```

To this the judge online of COJ says: "Time Limit Exceeded". Can someone explain why?

Comment: What does your code try to do? Questions have to be self-contained!

Comment: "Time Limited Exceeded" Why? Because your program exceeded the time limit for running the solution?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about an ongoing online challenge

Comment: It's not a competition or examination, is only one place where you can practice programming. Thanks for your help

Comment: My bet is that the online judge is broken.

Comment: Thank you for your help. This is not "make me the task" just do not understand why I get "Time Limited Exceeded ". As you know everything bro.

Comment: Why do you get that? YOUR CODE TOOK TOO LONG.

Answer (score -1):

Your could try to get rid of `std::endl` because it is slow. Instead, you use '\n'. The code is below:

```
#include<iostream>

  using namespace std;

  unsigned int t, n;

  int main(){



    cin >> t;

    while(t > 0 && cin >> n){
        cout<< ( n * 8 ) + 42 << '\n';
        t--;
    }

    cout.flush();
    return 0;
  }
```

Or you could try `printf()` to fasten your I/O.

This algorithm grows **linearly**, it should not be a limit factor. I believe **I/O** is the limiting factor. If you could find a algorithm that is **log N**, please tell me.

Someone vote it down because they believe doing I/O with standard out(stdout) is fast. However, std::endl **flush after every iteration**, which makes it slow.

Another idea is to use recursion, and you hope the judge system has good optimization on tail recursion(it is possible.). It may get a little faster, too.

On your own computer, you could even try to profile it to find the limiting factor, and if it is I/O, try the way above.

If it is still not fast enough, get rid of object-oriented design, use C and write direct to stdout instead use printf.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you very much. I will try what you say